# Facebook page scraping

Tags: php, facebook, curl, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrap a facebook page ( https://www.facebook.com/pages/PTSD/455847705426 )
I found this script to login to facebook.

```
<?php
$EMAIL = "me@mail.com";
$PASSWORD = "facebookPassword";

function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

if ($p) {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
}
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result) {
return $result;
} else {
return curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
}

$a = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,null,"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
$c = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,$b[1],"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
$cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";

/*
NOW TO JUST OPEN ANOTHER URL EDIT THE FIRST ARGUMENT OF THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION.
TO SEND SOME DATA EDIT THE LAST ARGUMENT.
*/
$page_html =  cURL("https://www.facebook.com/pages/PTSD/455847705426",null,$cookie,null);


?>
```

now variable $page_html have only few posts, moreover they are in very complex code
my questions are

1. how can I get all posts.
2. is there some other approach which return me complete and clear data.
3. is there some way to have all posts in json format.

please tell me if there is some useful tutorial or articles regarding this.

Regards

Comment: From the [Facebook terms and conditions](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php): You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission.

Comment: not going to help you break Facebooks terms of service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spend some time reading the [developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/). You can get all the posts as a JSON object from a page by setting up an app, then querying the graph api with a page access token.